# Create an API of GIS layers using Openlayer and tilecache

Tags: maps, openlayers

We already have GIS data for many layers created using openlayer,tilecache and mapnik. we want to create an API like maps.google for using our layers to other applications.  I don't know where to start and what is the methodology. Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks & Regards
Anju S B

Comment: This is a pretty broad question for Stack Overflow. Have you looked at Geoserver? It can be used to serve up tiles as WMS or WMTS to other applications, following common standards.

Comment: as far as I know, you can not set up tilecache only from the front end (by using javascript), but also need setting up from the backend. You can make your own api for the openlayer and mapnik though